# How can I test why sendmail / php isn't working?

Tags: php, sendmail

I have the php.ini configured correctly, I think...

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

php is working fine in general. phpinfo() looks fine.

I have a script I'm using to send a test message, and it claims to work..

```
<?php
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$from = "notarealaddy@domain.com";
$to = "myactualemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
$message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
echo "Test email sent";
?>
```

I always get a message that says: "Test email sent"

But nothing ever shows up in gmail??  What gives, how should I troubleshoot?

Comment: You actually dont build in a statement that checks if it's send. You simply just echo out `test email sent` (its send by the way). You should make an if else statement for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers))
{
echo "Test email sent";
}
```

This will check if the mail is sent and if it is, it will echo "Test email sent".

Comment: Just white-screens.  :(

Answer (score 1):

First and quickest: check your spam folder. Gmail has a tendency to filter out messages not coming from a well-established mail server.

Second, check the sendmail logs on the server sending the e-mails. The logs should tell you whether the receiving SMTP server has accepted the message.

That the `mail` function returns success only means that the local sendmail script accepted the e-mail, not necessarily that the e-mail was sent.

Comment: In his case, he just echo's the message, without it actually being checked. There is no if else statement performing or regulating his echo message. However, you are right on the part that the mail function indeed just simply accepts it, not that it was send.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with a contact form, double check your variables. In your case they are hard coded, but it is always good to perform a check. This is a simplified checker. (I edited out my checks for variables that are supposed to be send with the message)

```
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
         echo '<p>Message Send.</p>';
    } else {
         echo '<p>Something went wrong, not delivered.</p>';
    }
```

Comment: Changed $body to $message -- still got back "something went wrong"  :(

Comment: Well, at least you know now there is something wrong with maybe the mailfunction, cause the function wont accept it's feed. This means basically that either you function hasn't been set up propperly, (false written variables) or that your server is not configured to send these messages out. So maybe you set up the INI file wrong.

Answer (score 0):

mail() is boolean function.

```
$check = mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
var_dump($check);
```

var_dump will return either true or false.

if false, there are something wrong with the configurations or codes.

however, to briefly debug your mail() function, I need to know, what is your OS? what type of web server u use?

Comment: Hi there. This may very well be a great solution... but it's generally considered good Form to have a bit of explanation for why this solves the problem. Don't forget that newbies also come to Stack Overflow and want to know whether their problem might be also solved by this answer... so it helps them to figure that out :)

Comment: I changed the last two lines to that and it just white-screened.

Comment: @some1 updated answer. I need to know your OS and type of web server

Comment: @some1 check your sendmail path, is it correct? also check mail log (/var/log/mail.log). Otherwise, you also can try phpmailer class. More debugging options.